# Exporting Large DGML Diagram to XPS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, architecture, xps, dgml

I currently have a fairly large application (about 30k lines of code). I generated a dependency graph using the architecture tool within VS2010. I am trying to export it to XPS, as it states I can, and it will stop at about 300KB, and will not open in XPS viewer.

Any ideas on why it is stopping the export and corrupting the file, or is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can pass by another structure before converting your diagram to XPS, for example save it as an image, to do it :

```
Right-click the graph surface, and then click Copy Image.

Paste the image into another application.
```

Source : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380607%28v=vs.100%29.aspx