# How do you print a dgml file?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, dgml

I've got a dgml file created in Visual Studio 2017 that contains a schema for a database.

We refer to this regularly in our team so I want to print it out.

How can I do this?

I've tried the File->Print menu, but it is grayed out.

Also I've tried using Edit->Copy Image, but when I paste it into a third party image editor (that can print) the resolution of the copied image is so low that I can't read the text.

Comment: I've also seen this, but the command doesn't exist when I right click as instructed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578015/exporting-large-dgml-diagram-to-xps

Answer (score 5):

My workaround for now is to use [Share] [Export to Portable XPS...], then print the XPS document.

It doesn't work for complex DGML files, though. I sent a [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/135818/exporting-a-dgml-file-to-xps-creates-document-with.html) to Visual Studio Developer Community. Feel free to upvote there.

Comment: Yes, so basically there is no way to get a high res document / image one could print out. One workaround for this .xps bug might be to setup an environment with a virtual 10000x10000px resolution and try to screenshot the whole diagram while open in VS. Or simly take multiple snips at a zoomed-in level and stitch them together, which of course is tedious.